# How to communicate between a Lucene analyzer and a TokenFilter

Tags: lucene

I'd like to ask is there a recommended way to communicate between an analyzer and a tokenstream/tokenfilter in Lucene. I'd like to adjust analyzer behavior, particularly override [Analyzer.getPositionIncrementGap()](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html#getPositionIncrementGap%28java.lang.String%29) with a context specific method (e.g. the gap between the tokens should be dependent on what tokens are being analyzed and what tokens have been analyzed so far - probably the task has other possible solutions, but here I want to understand the principle of such a communication).

I've checked an analyzer instance (in debugger), and as it seems there're no "direct gates" from the Analyzer or its subclasses to the attributes storage, used by the current Tokenizer and/or Token Filters chain. Am I right?

Certainly I could create a custom Analyzer subclass and save a reference to one of the TokenFilters created in [Analyzer.createComponents()](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html#createComponents%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Reader%29) as a property of the Analyzer, and then access the Attributes storage through that property, but it seems to be quite ugly solution, doesn't it?